# web2py PDF - Where do I put this code?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

http://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/wiki/Web2Py#Sample_Table_Listing

This would be my first time using web2py, I'm using it because the example code is exactly what I need for part of a project.

My problem is I have no idea where to put this code. I'm using Google App Engine.

Comment: It's a kind of vague question, have you [tried anything yet](http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=web2py+appengine), where did you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand where to put that code, you'll need at least a basic understanding of how web2py applications are structured. I recommend at least looking at the [Overview chapter](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/03) of the book.

The function definitions shown (i.e., `report()`, `listing()`, and `invoice()`) would go in a controller file in your applications's '/controllers' folder (the scaffolding application includes a 'default.py' controller file, though you could rename that or create a new controller file). The calls to `db.define_table` would typically go in a model file in your application's '/models' folder (the scaffolding application includes a 'db.py' model file, though again, you could rename that or create a new model file).

Note, there was a recent discussion on the mailing list regarding [getting pyfpdf to work on GAE](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/web2py/5_aJJTrpOm4/discussion).

Comment: Thanks, I put it all in the controller it seems there was a syntax error with the sample code on the last line. (}}})